# Is it okay to put "cannot" in a present perfect tense?

Tags: grammar

Is it okay to say "we cannot have achieved this without the participation of your company.

Answer (score -1):

> We cannot have achieved this without the participation of your company.

This is grammatically incorrect. You should, instead, say:

> We **could** not have achieved this without the participation of your company.

... since the action of "achieving" here seems to be something that happened in the past. This is said as something like a "Thank you. We couldn't have done it without you." which is *thanking* someone.

If you want to *persuade* rather than *thank* "your company", you should say:

> We *cannot/can't* achieve this without the participation of your company.